# Text not appearing normally

Tags: html, css

Here is the text that I want it to show: résumé

And here is what is shown:

[image]

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="overlay-content">
  <a href="main">Home</a>
  <a href="/Downloads/Navjeeven Mann Resume.docx"> Résumé </a>
  <a href="finalgrade">Final Grade Calculator</a>
  <a href="second">Contact</a>
  <a id="social" href="https://github.com/Jeeven56">
    <img src="github.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use UTF-8 for encoding

Comment: Where is the sample text you want to show, i.e. resume?

Answer (score 2):

You probably solve the problem at this way ... but it's not your code... you need to use UTF-8 encoding for your characters

```html
<div class="overlay-content">
  <a href="main">Home</a>
  <a href="/Downloads/Navjeeven Mann Resume.docx"> R&eacute;sum&eacute; </a>
  <a href="finalgrade">Final Grade Calculator</a>
  <a href="second">Contact</a>
  <a id="social" href="https://github.com/Jeeven56">
    <img src="github.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `<head>` tag you must get sure to apply the value `UTF-8` to the `charset` attribute, like that:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  ...
</head>
```